# How to install Docker on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark

Tags: ubuntu, docker, installation, apt-get, gpg-signature

I followed the instructions on how to [install Docker CE for Ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1).  After I setup the repository, and then ran `sudo apt-get update`, I got the following error:

```
Err:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful Release                                             
404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:201d:5000:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
...
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
configuration details.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 (Artful Aardvark)

The following Docker GPG keys were added to my repo GPG keys file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Solution

Open your `sources.list` file as admin.

```
sudo emacs /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Find these two lines:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful stable
```

And change the word `artful` to `zesty` in both lines.  After the change, they should look like:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu zesty stable
```

Problem fixed, now install Docker CE with:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

## Explanation

Th problem is that as of this writing, a release file for Ubuntu 17.10 Artful Aardvark is [not available on Download Docker](https://gist.github.com/levsthings/0a49bfe20b25eeadd61ff0e204f50088).  Therefore, you have to use the release file for Ubuntu 17.04 (zesty) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.10 is now supported in the `edge` release, so you can use

`deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu artful edge`

as well.